# asynchronous access to a ConcurrentLinkedQueue using Producer and Consumer

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, io

By adjusting log levels and sleep duration, synchronization can be approximated.  However, I'm trying to implement asynchronous access to the `Deque` to populate the `Consumer`'s `stringFromProducer` field while also juggling output from a socket.

This output is nearly what I'm after:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ java -jar dist/MudSocketClient.jar 
-Dec 13, 2013 11:33:39 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: first
-Dec 13, 2013 11:33:39 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: java.util.NoSuchElementException
-Dec 13, 2013 11:33:41 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: java.util.NoSuchElementException
a
Dec 13, 2013 11:33:42 PM mudsocketclient.Producer run
INFO: a
-Dec 13, 2013 11:33:43 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: a
-Dec 13, 2013 11:33:43 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: java.util.NoSuchElementException
-Dec 13, 2013 11:33:45 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: java.util.NoSuchElementException
b
Dec 13, 2013 11:33:46 PM mudsocketclient.Producer run
INFO: b
-Dec 13, 2013 11:33:47 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: b
-Dec 13, 2013 11:33:47 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: java.util.NoSuchElementException
-Dec 13, 2013 11:33:49 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: java.util.NoSuchElementException
c
Dec 13, 2013 11:33:50 PM mudsocketclient.Producer run
INFO: c
-Dec 13, 2013 11:33:51 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: c
-Dec 13, 2013 11:33:51 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: java.util.NoSuchElementException
^Cthufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$
```

When a,b and c are entered they are echoed back by both the `Producer` and `Consumer`.  However, there's no output from the `Consumer`'s socket connection under this setup.

Poor-man's telnet driver:

```
public final class Telnet {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Telnet.class.getName());

    public Telnet() throws InterruptedException, UnknownHostException, IOException {
        startThreads();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, UnknownHostException, IOException {
        new Telnet();
    }

    public void startThreads() throws InterruptedException, UnknownHostException, IOException {
        final String host = "rainmaker.wunderground.com";
        final int port = 3000;
        Deque<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();
        queue.add("first");
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(queue));
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(queue));
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
    }
}
```

The `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is used as a cubby-hole to **asynchronously** pass `String` references between the `Consumer` and `Producer`.

The `Producer` code produces the correct output, but may be blocking `Consumer` from printing to the console:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName());
    private final Deque<String> queue;

    public Producer(Deque<String> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Scanner scanner;
            String line;
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            queue.add(line);
            log.info(line);   //echoes that line was entered correctly
        }
    }
}
```

The socket connection is perhaps problematic.  `Producer` might be blocking, somehow, or interfering with, `Consumer` so that the socket connection's remote output isn't getting printed through `System.out` calls:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName());
    final String host = "rainmaker.wunderground.com";
    final int port = 3000;
    private final Socket socket;
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;
    private final Deque<String> queue;
    private String stringFromProducer = "line scan of user input";

    public Consumer(Deque<String> queue) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        this.queue = queue;
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.print((char) inputStream.read());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.fine(ex.toString());
            }
            try {
                stringFromProducer = queue.pop();
                log.info(stringFromProducer);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
                log.info(ex.toString());  //spammy output
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.fine(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's very odd because adjusting the log levels and sleep duration in `Consumer` allows output like this:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ java -jar dist/MudSocketClient.jar 
-Dec 13, 2013 11:50:15 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: first
--a
Dec 13, 2013 11:50:18 PM mudsocketclient.Producer run
INFO: a
-Dec 13, 2013 11:50:19 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: a
---b-
Dec 13, 2013 11:50:25 PM mudsocketclient.Producer run
INFO: b
^C
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$
```

Which is actually the correct output, albeit v e r y   s l o w l y.

Keeping the same log levels, but decreasing the sleep to one millisecond gives:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ java -jar dist/MudSocketClient.jar 
-Dec 13, 2013 11:52:42 PM mudsocketclient.Consumer run
INFO: first
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*               Welcome to THE WEATHER UNDERGROUND telnet service!            *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*                                                                            *
*   National Weather Service information provided by Alden Electronics, Inc. *
*    and updated each minute as reports come in over our data feed.          *
*                                                                            *
*   **Note: If you cannot get past this opening screen, you must use a       *
*   different version of the "telnet" program--some of the ones for IBM      *
*   compatible PC's have a bug that prevents proper connection.              *
*                                                                            *
*           comments: jmasters@wunderground.com                              *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Press Return to continue:a
Dec 13, 2013 11:52:45 PM mudsocketclient.Producer run
INFO: a
b
Dec 13, 2013 11:52:47 PM mudsocketclient.Producer run
INFO: b
c
Dec 13, 2013 11:52:48 PM mudsocketclient.Producer run
INFO: c
^Cthufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$
```

So that now the socket connection output is printing, via `System.out`.  However, even though the log level for `stringFromProducer` is at `INFO`, there's now no output from `Consumer.stringFromProducer`!

How do I get output from `Producer`, echo of user input, plus echo of user input from `stringFromProducer` plus the remote connection output?  By fiddling with sleep duration and log levels I can, at best, manage two out of three.

`Producer` and `Consumer` are intended to run asynchronously.

I suppose that slowing the execution is approximating synchronization -- whereas synchronization is not my goal.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the Logger here. Why don't you use the normal System.out stream?

Comment: oh, only because sometimes I want it to print to the console visibly, and sometimes not.  some of the output is very spammy.  I'm thinking that there's something fishy with the while loop in Consumer.

Comment: Also, usually if you let thread communicate via concurrent data structures, you probably would like to use a blocking FIFO (like a pipe?). Why did you choose a Deque (LIFO?). That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: FIFO is correct, I'll change that, thanks.  However, I don't think that I want anything blocked, I want both to keep running..?

Comment: @Thufir - do they have something else to do? mwhs is right - as posted, block it up and get rid of the latency-generating sleep call.

Comment: btw: non-blocking does not mean something is doing to happen faster in parallel. In most cases you will want to wait for data t be available on the queue anyways, right? Try the blocking queue and re-design the thread that prints the output. Try the take method to read [BlockingQueue#take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take()) (blocking) and the offer method to write (non-blocking).

Comment: @MartinJames yes, the threads are waiting for input, either local or remote.  I kludged together an alternate approach:  https://github.com/THUFIR/MudSocketClient/tree/004connects_to_weather_underground/src/mudsocketclient   however, it doesn't handle threading an interesting way, where I learn anything.  It just works.   It might have trouble with some telnet data, but it's an interactive telnet client with asynchronous i/o.